# How to discard the output from a system command?

Tags: c, linux, output-redirect

I recently wrote this code to execute system command in C. I just want to measure time performed by this system command.

However, I don't want the output results to be displayed upon executing this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    system("ls");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I discard the output from the system command?

Comment: If you don't want the result to be printed, where do you want them to go?

Comment: What's the point of listing files with `ls` at all? The whole point of running ls is to put a listing of files and folders on the terminal. If you don't want  to do that, don't run ls. This is an XY problem - *I'm doing the wrong thing to get something done, but now it's causing me a second problem. How do I fix the second problem?* You don't; fix the first and the second goes  away.

Comment: If you want to get the list of files in a directory to operate on them within your program, use the `DIR` type.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: i just want to measure time performed by this system command.

Comment: Redirect output to >/dev/null

Comment: Part of that time is producing output on the terminal, so you're not *measuring time performed* at all.

Comment: @user9179677: Why not just run `time ls >/dev/null`, and skip the wrapping? What is the wrapping in C doing (aside from adding overhead by changing a single process launch for `ls` into three, one for your program, one for the shell to run `ls` in, and one for `ls`)?

Comment: Why do you want to run a system command to list files, but not see what files are listed? I suggest `//system("ls");` That takes 0 time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `system()` from C, a shell is invoked to interpret your command. This means you can use shell redirects:

```
system("ls > /dev/null");
```

and if you want errors to also be suppressed

```
system("ls > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

However, due to the overhead of running a shell and the fragility of constructing shell commands, it's better to avoid `system()` when you can.

Comment: _system call_ is a well-defined term which may be confusing in this context. I think that some backticks can help: `system()` calls

Comment: It is indeed best to avoid `system()`.  Its use of the shell and special signal-handling behavior give it a _single_ legitimate use: executing a shell command requested by the user (e.g., via `!` in `vi`).

Comment: @DavisHerring Even then it's arguably better to run the user's login shell instead of `/bin/sh` as used by `system()`

Comment: But my command `system("chcp 936")` there is no way to redirect the output, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure time by the system command, you can redirect standout and stderr in the system call.  Not sure this is the most elegant, but it works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    system("ls >/dev/null 2>&1");
}
```

Note that you need the `<stdlib.h>` headers for `system`.

Comment: You suggest redirecting stdout and stderr but the example you provide only redirects stdout.

Comment: @Turn you're right, I edited the answer.  Although, fwiw, ls shouldn't really print anything on stderr ;)  And we can only hope that whatever the OP is trying to achieve isn't the kind of thing which has to scale or account for weird edge cases because God knows this approach is sorta crazy in the first place.