# How to run a process and quit after the script is over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, subprocess, x11

[I have asked a question how to run a clipboard clearing command from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490382/how-to-clear-both-clipboards-securely-in-gnome-from-python), and [I got a good answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48495661/9213435):

```
subprocess.run("xclip",stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
subprocess.run(["xclip","-selection","clipboard"],input="")
```

This seem to work in python, but there is a problem, it leaves the process open. Actually it opens 2 processes, one `xclip` and one with `xclip -selection clipboard` parameters.

And it seems like they are zombie processes, they remain there indefinitely, **until** you copy-paste something again. After that both of them dissapear.

So I have run the script from an USB drive's directory, and it doesn't let you remove the USB drive, it says "USB drive busy", until the processes don't close.

So either I copy something new into the clipboard, otherwise the process remains there indefinitely, like a zombie.

**Is it possible to just close the process after the python script ends**? Since there is no reason for that process to remain open after the python script has ran.

Comment: you can copy something to clipboard via python code after executing your subprocess, give what it needs to be closed (might work - not sure) OR this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25476462/5585424

Comment: @AnkushRathi if I'd copy something to the clipboard then it would be pointless to clear it. My goal is to clean the clipboard, not to replace it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to read `xclip`'s source to see if the parent (your direct child) waits until the selection has been claimed to exit.  If not, you would race with the actual work if you killed anything.  You can use `xsel -c` (as was suggested in the other question); to solve *just* the unmounting problem, you can simply change the current directory of the child:

```
subprocess.run("xclip",stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,cwd="/")
```